# Making background image and items in grid responsive

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Im new to HTML/CSS & grid

I want to make the background image and the items in the grid responsive.

Could you'll please let me know what im doing wrong or help me out

```css
.angry-grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
 
}

 .charCoal-items{
   display: grid; 
   grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 10px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/shilajit-is-ayurvedic-medicine-found-primarily-rocks-himalayas-selective-focus_466689-90021_1.png?v=1669684516");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   background-position: center center;
}

.charCoal-items p{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#item-1 {
    background-color: rgba(187, 170, 126, 0.7);
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2 ; 
}

#item-2 {

   background-color: rgba(187, 170, 126, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50px;
margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
    width: 80%;
   grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-column-end:4 ;
   
}

#item-1 p,
#item-2 p{
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}


#item-2 p:first-child,
#item-1 p:first-child{
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 24px;

}

#item-2 p:last-child,
#item-1 p:last-child{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 34px;

} 

/* @media all and (max-width: 1199px){
  
 .charCoal-items {

    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
} */

@media all and (max-width: 799px) {

  .charCoal-items {
    
    
  }

}

  .charCoal-items p{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
}

@media all and (max-width: 599px){
  
  .charCoal-items p{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="angry-grid">
  <div class="charCoal-items">
<!--     <div id="item-0">
      
    </div> -->
    <div id="item-1"><p>Ayurvedic Rasa (Taste) & Flavor Profile: </p>
  <p>Astringent, Savory, Bitter, Mildly Smokey, and Earthy flavor.</p>
    </div>
  <div id="item-2"><p>Dosha Compatibility: </p>
  <p>With inherent heating properties, it helps reinvigorate a sluggish Kapha dosha and ground the erratic nature of the Vata dosha, though it can aggravate the Pitta dosha.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is what im trying to achieve
[image]

Here is the codepen: `https://codepen.io/pen/tour/welcome/start`

If any website explanation link will also be helpful

```css
.angry-grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
 
}

 .charCoal-items{
   display: grid; 
   grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 10px;
   width: 100%;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="angry-grid">
  <div class="charCoal-items">
<!--     <div id="item-0">
      
    </div> -->
    <div id="item-1"><p>Ayurvedic Rasa (Taste) & Flavor Profile: </p>
  <p>Astringent, Savory, Bitter, Mildly Smokey, and Earthy flavor.</p>
    </div>
  <div id="item-2"><p>Dosha Compatibility: </p>
  <p>With inherent heating properties, it helps reinvigorate a sluggish Kapha dosha and ground the erratic nature of the Vata dosha, though it can aggravate the Pitta dosha.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: the codepen link is not correct

Comment: Here is codepen link:https://codepen.io/GreyWor42781165/pen/QWxVOVz

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `background-size: auto;` or `background-size: cover;`

```css
.angry-grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
 
}

 .charCoal-items{
   display: grid; 
   grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 10px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/shilajit-is-ayurvedic-medicine-found-primarily-rocks-himalayas-selective-focus_466689-90021_1.png?v=1669684516");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: auto;
}

.charCoal-items p{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#item-1 {
    background-color: rgba(187, 170, 126, 0.7);
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2 ; 
}

#item-2 {

   background-color: rgba(187, 170, 126, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50px;
margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
    width: 80%;
   grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-column-end:4 ;
   
}

#item-1 p,
#item-2 p{
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}


#item-2 p:first-child,
#item-1 p:first-child{
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 24px;

}

#item-2 p:last-child,
#item-1 p:last-child{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 34px;

} 

/* @media all and (max-width: 1199px){
  
 .charCoal-items {

    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
} */

@media all and (max-width: 799px) {

  .charCoal-items {
    
    
  }

}

  .charCoal-items p{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
}

@media all and (max-width: 599px){
  
  .charCoal-items p{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="angry-grid">
  <div class="charCoal-items">
<!--     <div id="item-0">
      
    </div> -->
    <div id="item-1"><p>Ayurvedic Rasa (Taste) & Flavor Profile: </p>
  <p>Astringent, Savory, Bitter, Mildly Smokey, and Earthy flavor.</p>
    </div>
  <div id="item-2"><p>Dosha Compatibility: </p>
  <p>With inherent heating properties, it helps reinvigorate a sluggish Kapha dosha and ground the erratic nature of the Vata dosha, though it can aggravate the Pitta dosha.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```